# Enabling Alt+Tab buffer switching like Windows or Firefox in Vim

Tags: vim, buffer, switching

How do I set up a buffer switch like Alt-Tab on Windows:? It cycles through a list sorted by last access first? So if I pressed Alt+Tab, I'd get the last accessed buffer. If I pressed it again, I would go back to the first file. If I pressed Alt+(Tab,Tab) I would go the second to last access buffer. Unlike the existing Ctrl+6 in Vim, I wouldn't want unopened buffers to be a part of the list.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is my white whale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LustyJuggler](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2050) works almost exactly as you describe.

Hit `<leader>b` to open a list of buffers with the most recent first, type a couple of letters to narrow the list down to the one you want and finally `<CR>` to open it.

I personnaly use its sibling LustyExplorer which offers the same feature plus a similar one for the filesystem and a similarly designed "search in buffers" as well.

Comment: I ended up using LustyJuggler so I could recreate my familiar kaystrokes using [some mappings](https://github.com/mattalexx/dotfiles/commit/7c8514606b81d633ef8aad9819cee1b85e377e3e). It's not `<C-Tab>`, `<C-Tab><C-Tab>`, and `<C-Tab><C-Tab><C-Tab>`, which is what I'm used to, but that's okay. This will soon become a part of my fingers. Thanks!

Comment: Vim is a world of its own. You'll find it's sometimes quite hard to apply your ancient habits and workflow. It'll pay if you do things the Vim way.

Comment: Yes, that's what I've found.

Comment: By the way, I've found an even better solution: [LustyJugglerAltTabMode](https://github.com/sjbach/lusty/blob/master/plugin/lusty-juggler.vim#L59).

Comment: @MattAlexander I almost missed this comment! By the way, here's a permalink: https://github.com/sjbach/lusty/blob/a9b501e76c458c0cc91cf59f6e2fab0e1abc06a3/plugin/lusty-juggler.vim#L107

Answer (score 0):

I like the minibufexplorer plugin. It gives you a small list of open buffers at the top of a windows, that sort of looks like the tabbar in Firefox, and it allows you to close buffers (or at least remove them from the list).

It allows you to use ctrl-tab and shift-ctrl-tab to navigate backwards and forward through the list of tabs, if you want to. Not alt, though, but I guess you could make a map to do that yourself.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159

Comment: The backwards and forwards switching you describe is based on a list sorted by time opened, not last viewed.